# how to split multiple valued single row into multiple individual rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have CSV file which has multiple "values" in complex form for single "id" and 
i want that multiple values to split in different rows with respect to its "id".

My CSV file:

```
# To read df1=pandas.read_csv('krish.csv',encoding="ISO-8859-1")
# File have data even like 1.50% (P,KR,AU) 0.2¢/kg (AX,AU)
id  value
100.3   Free (A+,BH,CA) 0.1¢/kg (AX)
200.1   Free (MA, MX,OM)
321.5   Free (BH,CA) 1.70% (P) 7% (PE) 12.3% (KR)
```

OUTPUT I WANT FOR MY INPUT GIVEN ABOVE :

[image: Required output]

OUTPUT WHICH GOT ON MY CODE AND FOR WHAT I TRIED
[image: Required output]

Comment: is it only the `Free` tag that can have multiple elements?

Comment: No it can be even like 1.70% (P,KR,AU)

Comment: ok, have a look at my answer and let me know if it fit your needs

Comment: Hey SS would you accept my answer if you don't have anything more to add? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there are more efficient/elegant ways, but this should work

```py
def split_elements(s):
    elements = s[s.find('(')+1:-1].split(',')
    key = s[:s.find('(')]
    return ['{} ({})'.format(key, el) for el in elements]

input_data = {'values': ['Free (A+,BH,CA) 0.1¢/kg (AX)', 'Free (MA, MX,OM)', 'Free (BH,CA) 1.70% (P) 7% (PE) 12.3% (KR)'], 'ids': [100.3, 200.1, 321.5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(input_data)

temp_values = []
temp_ids = []
# iterate through rows
for idr, r in df.iterrows():
    # extract elements
    elements = [el.strip()+')' for el in r['values'].split(')') if el != '']
    # split subelements
    for element in elements:
        split_el = split_elements(element)
        temp_values.extend(split_el)
        temp_ids.extend([r['ids']]*len(split_el))
# create dataset
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ids': temp_ids, 'values': temp_values})
df1.set_index('ids')
```

Which gives

```sh
ids     values
100.3   Free (A+)
100.3   Free (BH)
100.3   Free (CA)
100.3   0.1¢/kg (AX)
200.1   Free (MA)
200.1   Free ( MX)
200.1   Free (OM)
321.5   Free (BH)
321.5   Free (CA)
321.5   1.70% (P)
321.5   7% (PE)
321.5   12.3% (KR)
```

Comment: I have my ID column which as i have mentioned in my input

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: In your code you have used input with only my "value " column but i need my "id" data be to same Just now i edited my Id values it will be similar to that can you please have a look sir

Comment: Please have a look at my input sir

Comment: Yeah, that was not there before, how could I know? What do you want to do with your id? Please explain yourself otherwise this will take ages to solve.

Comment: Each individual "id" have values respectively and i can query or search particular value based on those id's . And thts the structure of my id. Which will be in Float

Comment: I still cannot understand. If I look at the picture you posted after the message `OUTPUT I WANT FOR MY INPUT GIVEN ABOVE :` this is what I achieved with my code. Update that picture to reflect the result you're looking after and then I'll update my answer accordingly